# b0rked eclipse / IBM RAD

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, block, ibm-rad

Neither Eclipse nor IBM RAD 8 work. When these IDE validate Java, they report false errors which blocks the build. Evidence:

[image]

Even though I comment out the code it is reporting an error. I do clean, I do build, I make a completely new project from scratch, I switch between Eclipse and IBM RAD 8 and they couldn't even get code validation to work in these IDE:s. When I delete the code part it complains about, the IDe finds the code that it says is not there so the report is self-contradictory.

Comment: This is a statement of fact (not even verifiable), but not a question.

Comment: I had not put my code in a package. That's why. It works after I put it in a package. It should work from default package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you should not share workspaces between Eclipse variants.  The .project configuration file is not designed for that.

Unzip a fresh Eclipse, make a fresh workspace and reimport your sources from your source repository.  If that works, drop your current, faulty workspace.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had not put my code in a package. That's why. It works after I put it in a package. It should work from default package.

Answer (score 3):

Try hitting Project -> Clean and see if it solves the problem :)

Comment: I tried it many times but it just made the errrors come back. Finally I unzipped a fresh version of Eclipse and reconfigured everything. It turns out that my mistake was that I didn't put my classes in a package. As soon as I put my classes in a package everything works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you managed to somehow make the Eclipse Java builder not work anymore. There are lots of reasons like a defective .project file, badly behaving other plugins installed, the builder being disabled in the project configuration.

Instead of checking all those, go with the suggestion of Thorbjørn and re-install Eclipse and checkout your code into a new workspace.

Comment: The reason was that I hadn't put my code in a package. I used the default package which somehow screwed up even command-line compiling. I tried compiled everything from the command line and got `symbol not found`and then I realized that the compiler wasn't finding my classes so I put everything in a package and now it works :-)